# AC not starting, fuse on control board blown

Tags: hvac

My ac was working before winter (I tested it after installing new contactor and new capacitor).
During the winter I added humidifier and did rewiring however everything is connected like shown on the ecobee menu and I believe it is all correct (the only think I can think off is the fact that y and c are swapped at ac unit).
Today I tried to turn on ac but my ecobee just restarted.
After 10min I tried again and ecobee again restarted when trying to start ac.
I left and after 10min I heard ac tried to start but after 3seconds it stopped. Ecobee was completely off and I found that 3A fuse is blown on the board.
Any idea what might be happening? Why will fuse be blown? Thanks

[image: wiring diagram]

Thanks everyone for answers. Indeed I didn't test ac as I didn't wanted to start ac during cold November. Heating, fan and humidifier were working perfectly during winter. Before posting I checked wiring. Below you can see how it is connected and I believe it is correct. Can you help to check and comment? Do you still believe it is wiring issue? Thanks

[[image: wiring][2]]

[image: ecobee]

[image: ecpbee]

Comment: Did you test everything after adding the humidifier? It sounds like what you're really facing here is that the AC has not worked since you rewired it. Given the available evidence, that leaves it looking like something is miswired.

Comment: We can not confirm your wiring based on this information. Ecobee will send 24VAC signal on the G, Y1 and W1. If you have a mistake in those 3 wires it can produce a short circuit that will blow the fuse. In cooling mode it will send 24V on the Y1 for the compressor and 24V on the G for the fan.

Comment: You tested it. Then you added stuff and rewired it. But didn't test it. Q.E.D. it's the rewiring. Set aside the belief that it's all correct and go looking for the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely a wiring error. Get some replacement fuses, disconnect everything, and then re-connect the wires a few at a time.

- To start, get the Ecobee powering on. Looks like you have a 7-conductor thermostat cable. Connect that red to the Ecobee RH and to furnace R. Connect blue of that same cable to Ecobee C and to furnace C. Close the door of the furnace blower compartment and confirm that the Ecobee powers on, then continue to the next step or troubleshoot until the Ecobee does power on.
- Connect wiring for Ecobee control of the fan. Connect the green of the thermostat cable to Ecobee G and to furnace G. Close the blower door, wait for the Ecobee to start, set it to "Fan On" mode. Confirm the fan comes on.
- Connect wiring for Ecobee control of the heat. Connect the white of the thermostat cable to Ecobee W1 and furnace W. Test.
- Connect wiring for Ecobee control of the air conditioner. Connect the yellow of the thermostat cable to Ecobee Y1 and to furnace Y. Also connect the red of the AC control cable to furnace Y1, and the white of the AC control cable to furnace C. Close the blower door, wait for the Ecobee to start, and set it to Cool with a temperature lower than the current room temperature. Confirm that the air conditioner and the blower come on. There may be a delay as long as 5 minutes depending on settings of the thermostat.
- Connect the humidifier wiring and test (choose heat mode, adjust the humidity and temperature settings higher than the ambient levels, etc).

If everything "just works" then congratulations, there was a wiring error that is now resolved.

If something doesn't work correctly then you may need to go through the Ecobee wiring setup process to cause it to re-detect the kind of system you have. There could also be damage to any of the cables, such as a pinch and short to the furnace case, duct work, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I spend today 3h rewiring and testing and ultimately found out that after replacing fuse ecobee is constantly senidn 24v to the ac. I called ecobee and they are sending me new thermostat as seems this one somehow broke down. Thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right and the wiring is messed up somewhere.

Ecobee will send 24VAC signal on the G, Y1 and W1.

If you have a mistake in those 3 wires it can produce a short circuit that will blow the fuse.

In cooling mode it will send 24V on the Y1 for the compressor and 24V on the G for the fan.

If one of those is connected to C (common) by mistake, it will create a short circuit and blow the fuse.